# How would I use the AES/CCM/NoPadding cipher from java in golang?

Tags: java, go, aes

I need to use the AES/CCM/NoPadding cipher (from java) in golang, but I can't find anything about aes-ccm in the std lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this related to the usage of it in SSL/TLS? It seems some golang people do not want to support it for TLS: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27484 but most TLS implementations offer mostly other ciphers suites.

However if it is not related to TLS maybe you may want to look at other peoples effort to implement it like:

- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pschlump/AesCCM
- https://gist.github.com/hirochachacha/abb76ff71573dea2ef42

See for some documentation on implementing this also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610 about AES CCM
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4309 (for CCM use in IPsec Encapsulating Security Payload)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6655 (for CCM use in TLS)

You will also typically find more in-depth expertise around crypto on crypto.stackexchange.com, e.g.:

- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=aes+ccm
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44157/an-example-of-ccm-aes-mode